# MDI Menustrip dropdown on first item

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a application that's using a MDI form with a menustrip but encountering the following problem, when opening serveral forms and then opening the arrival list afterwards it shows a dropdown as shown in the image below:

[image]

Is it possible to disable this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you mean that the menustrip is listing the items from your menu line? And how should your drop down menu look like otherwise? Or do you want to prevent it from dropping down while other forms are opened? Be more clear, please.

Comment: @D. Petrov I would like to prevent it from dropping down, In my menustrip I have 8 items when clicking on either of those it opens the correspondending form. When clicking on Arrival List while other forms are already open I would like to achieve that it just opens the form and doesn't show the dropdown.

Comment: I guess those drop down items have been added somehow, either programmatically or manually. Is this dropdown listing all the items in your menustrip or just the forms shown. And at all, when is it appearing and does it also pop-up when there are no forms shown? That's strange, maybe you'd like to share a bit of code. I may be missing something typical about this behaviour, but I think it's not explainable with "default".

Comment: Select your `MenuStrip` at designer, in properties windows, right click on `MdiWindowListItem` and click `Reset`

Comment: It is showing all the forms that have been opened, It does not pop-up when there are no forms shown and. It only appears when I have a form opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have set [`MdiWindowListItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.mdiwindowlistitem(v=vs.110).aspx) for your `MenuStrip` and it's showing list of MDI child forms automatically.

To remove it, Select your `MenuStrip` at designer, in properties windows, right click on `MdiWindowListItem` and click `Reset`

Comment: That fixed it, Thank you!

Comment: I was totally unaware of that property... Will have to keep it in mind!

Comment: @D.Petrov [How to: Create an MDI Window List with MenuStrip (Windows Forms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171654(v=vs.110).aspx)